# setFormula en google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo un script para agregar una formula, y los datos están bien, pero se pega como texto o algo similar porque la celda da:

> #Error : Error de analisis de Formula

Pero si edito la celda y le doy <kbd>Enter</kbd> la formula funciona.

```
var formula1 = "=BUSCARV(B5283,BASE!A:E,5,FALSO)";  
var rangocopia = spreadsheet.getRange("C1");
rangocopia.setFormula(formula1);
```

¿Alguna idea?

Gracias.

Comment: Prueba si funciona con una fórmula más sencilla como `=SUM(B3:B4)` o algo así.

Comment: Yo solucione algo similar poniendo las funciones en ingles.

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero intentar usando el nombre en inglés de la función, específicamente, en lugar de BUSCARV usar VLOOKUP

Lo anterior porque Google es una compañia americana y por varios años las funciones sólo estaban disponibles en inglés. Me imagino que del lado del cliente tiene una diccionario que hace la traducción de los nombre de las funciones y que en los servidores de Google se guardan "en inglés".