# Quiero escribir varias fórmulas en google sheets con google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Necesito escribir varias formulas en google sheets, por medio de google apps script. Para que no sea muy lento el script, usé setValues() y escribí las fórmulas (que son SUMA y SUMAR.SI) como string, pero aunque se escriben correctamente en el sheets, no las lee bien y me aparece un error #¿NOMBRE?
Agrego un ejemplo simplificado.

```
function escribirFormulas(){
  var ssHoja5 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxx').getSheetByName('Hoja 5')
   var array = [['=SUMA(25+25)','=SUMA(2+2)'],['=SUMA(25+25)','=SUMA(2+2)']]
   ssHoja5.getRange('A1:B2').setValues(array)
}
```

[image: muestra del error en el spreadsheet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Independientemente de la configuración de tu cuenta y de la configuración de la hoja de cálculo, cuando se agregan fórmulas usando Google Apps Script, en lugar de usar los nombres de las funciones en español, en este caso `SUMA`, se debe  usar los nombres de las funciones en inglés, en este caso `SUM`.

Por cierto, en lugar de usar `setValues` lo apropiado sería usar `setFormulas`.

Relacionado

- [setFormula en google script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/237585/65)

Referencias

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range##setformulasformulas

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ayudó mucho. No puedo usar `setFormulas` porque el array contiene otros valores que no son fórmulas. Por ejemplo:
`var array = [['=SUM(25+25)','15'],['=SUM(25+25)','5)']]` 
Cuál sería la manera ideal para escribir este array.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. El código de la pregunta sólo incluye fórmulas, las preguntas de seguimiento deben publicarse como nuevas preguntas (en este caso hace falta mayor contexto). Por cierto, si no lo has hecho aún, favor de leer [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien responde mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)